# Windows Phone - Populate ListBox with Json

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a Json file saved in "IsolatedStorage" (json.html) and i need populate a "ListBox" with the field "FName" (from Json file).

> The Json below, is stored in file (json.html) and saved in
>   IsolatedStorage. The file will be changed as necessary (synchronized
>   with web server). So I need that fields as "FNome" and "FEstado"
>   received information from "json.html".

My Json file:

```
{"xId":"52","result":{"type":"Basico.Bean.MunicipioClass.TMunicipio","id":1,"fields":{"FRefCount":0,"FId":52,"FNome":"Sumare","FEstado":"SP","FPais":"Brasil"}}}
```

My class from Json:

```
        public class Fields
    {
        public int FId { get; set; }
        public string FNome { get; set; }
        public string FEstado { get; set; }
        public string FPais { get; set; }
    }
```

My ListBox:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" 
             Height="192" Width="456" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             BorderThickness="5"
             Padding="5"
             BorderBrush="White"
             FontSize="30"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                    <ListBox.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </ListBox.Background>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FNome}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="10" Text="{Binding FEstado}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not using [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) or anything "fancy", so here's (almost) minimal working example for you to study.

First, right-click on your project, select `Manage NuGet Packages` and install `Json.NET` dependency. Json.NET package helps you handle JSON formatted data.

After installation, this would be your `MainWindow.xaml`. Here you define your ListBox and template you want to use when showing each ListBox item.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="100"
        Width="420">

    <Grid>
        <!-- Your ListBox, notice the ItemsSource -->
        <ListBox 
             Height="50" 
             Width="400"
             FontSize="30"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

            <!-- Template to display each item -->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- Bind UI controls to properties you want to display -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FId}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FPais}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FNome}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding FEstado}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And your code-behind, namely `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. For clarity, json is defined as const string.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace MyWpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            // Your JSON string
            const string json = 
                "{'xId':'52'," +
                "  'result':{" + 
                "    'type':'Basico.Bean.MunicipioClass.TMunicipio'," +
                "    'id':1," + 
                "    'fields':{" + 
                "      'FRefCount':0," +
                "      'FId':52," + 
                "      'FNome':'Sumare'," + 
                "      'FEstado':'SP'," + 
                "      'FPais':'Brasil'" + 
                "    }" + 
                "  }" + 
                "}";

            // Parse as JObject
            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

            // Extract what you need, the "fields" property
            JToken jToken = jObj["result"]["fields"];

            // Convert as Fields class instance
            Fields fields = jToken.ToObject<Fields>();

            // Assign to Items property, which is used as ListBox's ItemsSource
            // In real application you'd probably want to have more than one item :)
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Fields>() { fields };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Fields> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then, of course, you need you `Fields` class, too. You can "map" JSON to C# class autamagically if property names match. If you want to use other name in your class properties, say plain `Id` instead of `FId`, then you need to mark the property with JsonProperty attribute. For example `[JsonProperty(PropetyName = "FId)]`.

```
public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FId")]
    public int FId { get; set; }

    public string FNome { get; set; }
    public string FEstado { get; set; }
    public string FPais { get; set; }
}
```

Running the "application" gives you the following output

[image]

Comment: @Viitala, If the Json file is modified? I need that code showing the file in isolatedStorage, because the file will be changed.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Maybe you could edit your question and be more verbose about it?

Comment: Well, you'd just open the JSON file from IsoStore and parse it again?

Comment: ...ok, comments are getting out of hand. But you'd just read it as string from IsoStore...

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: Interwebs is full of examples using IsoStore, Google it.